# How to measure the rate of false positives in a Bloom Filter

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, computer-science, probability, bloom-filter

You have a bloom filter, and you want to measure the rate of false positives, practically (not theoretically).

How do you go about it?

Do you insert N elements into it and count the number of hash collisions and divide by N, and that's it?

Or do you insert N elements and then do membership tests for all other elements which were not inserted (which is infinite in general)?

Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that your calculations say you'll have a false positive rate of X when there are N items in the Bloom filter.

Generate 2N unique random keys. Place half of them into the Bloom filter. Now test with the other half. You know the keys are unique, so any "positive" hit you get will be a false positive.

Compare your experimental result with the computed result.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I would, and thank you very much for the answer. Also, is there any reason why you'd generate 2N random keys and not, say, 10N, or KN for some other K?

Comment: I think 2N items would be sufficient to get a good read on the false positive rate. I suppose it would be interesting to see how it changes with more keys. Although the FP rate increases as you add more items.

Comment: Exactly! So 2N seems as arbitrary as 100N, but they'd give vastly different false positive rates, I don't know which FP rate would be "correct", if any.

Comment: @DiegoAlonso The false positive rate is expressed as a percentage of error at a particular number of keys in the structure. So if you want to know how close your filter comes to the theoretical FP percentage when there are N keys, generate N random keys and for each one test and insert. Keep track of the accumulated FP rate and compare against the calculated value.